# What means to publish views/ideas are used, instead of blogs, among mathematicians today?

Tags: self-learning, education, research

My question is motivated by the feeling that some mathematics blogs publish less and less over time. Are there other communication means which are used now instead with a similar role, or is it because it turns out that for a mathematician it is just too distracting?

Answer (score 0):

Do check out Terence Tao's blog. He certainly publishes very frequently on his blog.

Another place to "publish" is arXiv.

Finally we have the traditional journals.

Comment: arXiv is used for more than two decades now, my question was (I am sorry if it was not clear) about new means of communication alternative to blogs, if there are such.

Comment: I see... Not that I know of.